# Scrivener: Editing the source files

Tags: tools, scrivener

I'm away from the house but I have my .scriv file on cloud storage.

My question is, can I get to a particular chapter in my story and make some quick edits? Will changing these files break the program when I launch it next?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you using scrivener on another computer to edit it? If so, you shouldn't have any issues, just make sure you save, and let your cloud platform fully sync before you go to work on your main computer again.

If you're not using scrivener, make a backup of the file before you try!

Comment: Nope. This is without access to the software entirely. On Google Drive if I look at the .scriv file, it's folder. I can go in and see various other folders, each containing my chapters/scripts etc. If I modify these files within the .scriv file outside of access to Scrivener, what'll happen?

Comment: I just made a test file in scrivener, then edited the .rtf files inside of the Docs folder. When I opened scrivener again all the changes were there. So it looks like it works on a basic level. Not sure how it will react if you've got a lot of annotations or some of the more advanced Scrivener features at play, so definitely make a backup just incase. As well, be careful if you have scrivener open elsewhere and it tries to write to the files while you're editing the files manually.

Answer (score 3):

I work on my Scrivener files outside of Scrivener (using Vim and Multimarkdown Composer) more than I do inside.

To do so, set Scrivener to sync your project using external files (File > Sync > with External Folder) to a folder in Dropbox (or whatever syncing service you are using). I recommend setting Scrivener to automatically sync on opening and closing a project, which is an option available in the dialog when you are setting it up.

Then your Scrivener documents will all be stored as individual files that you can edit at will with whatever editor suits your fancy on whatever computer/device has access to your synced files. When you open the project, Scrivener will check and sync that folder to bring in your edits. If you add new documents to that folder, Scrivener detects them on the next sync and verifies you want to bring them into the project. They end up in your research folder until you put them in the proper place.

I work primarily in Markdown, but it works fine with RTF files and RTF capable editors as well.

This is a significantly safer alternative than opening .scriv files on multiple computers.

Comment: Why is this safer than opening .scriv files on multiple computers? Or do you mean, at the same time? Because I constantly work on my .scriv files from several computers (via Dropbox), only not at the same time, of course.

Comment: Safer because a) editing the .scriv file means that if something goes wrong with the sync you endanger the entire project and, it follows, b) carelessness with things like forgetting to close Scrivener on one computer and then making changes can lead to more difficult problem. The safety is only in the possibility of human error, not technical!